# extends BaseActivity onclick listening not working when the activity implements onclick listener

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a baseactivity for my navigation drawer.

this navigation drawer has a onclick listener:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
```

...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Pic:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, P_Activity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

it works nice when the class that extends BaseActivity hasn't a click listener too.
but if it is like this:

```
public class Upload extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

the click on baseactivity will not work.
any ideas why and how to solve?

Comment: mPic.setOnClickListener(this); call this line in BaseActivity?

Comment: yeah,         `image.setClickable(true);
        image.setOnClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding the method `public void onClick(View v)` in class `Upload`. In method `Upload.onClick(View v)` call `super`

```
public class Upload extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) { 
      if (something) {
         // do something
      } else {
          super.onClick(v);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I add `super` after my `switch (v.getId()) { cases } super` and it works. is it ok too?

Comment: this is up to you, if it's working how you expect, it's ok.